# Trying to align google charts with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I'm trying to centre the example chart provided by google: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start
I've used the basic css centering i know (`margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;`), But nothing seems to work. I've only been working with text and images up to this point, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the basic code I'm laying around with (including the google charts javascript)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <style> 

  div.chart_div {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px; }

</style>

<!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                       'width':400,
                       'height':300};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>

</head> <body>

    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>


</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stovroz is totally right!

In CSS you define `div.chart_div` as a class; but in HTML you define as a `div#chart_div` ID.

Following CSS code normally use to center everything in a page..

```
<style> 
body{ text-align: center;}
#chart_div{width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS `div.chart_div` is targeting a div of **class**="chart_div" but you've got a div of **id**="chart_div". Use # in CSS to target IDs, i.e. `div#chart_div`.